# Reactjs and issue with closures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, closures, render

I have render method in my react class.  looping through data, i am attaching the onClick event.  However, when onClick is called, it is always attaching the last time in the list.
Here is my code.

```
for (let item in summaryData) {
  var section = summaryData[item];
  for (var i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {
      var identity = (section[i].name).split('|');
      items.push(
        <tr key={`team-${item}-row-${i}`}>
          <th scope="row">{item}</th>              

          <td><a href="#" onClick={() => this.handleShowModal(identity[0], identity[1], 'inactive')}>
            {section[i].myData.myList}
          </a></td>              
      );}}
```

When I call handleShowModal, it always brings up the last record in the list for identity[0] and identity[1]

This is related to closures and when i tried to wrap the items.push into a (function(j){....})(i), it doesn't recognize handleShowModal function.

Can anyone suggest how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
<td><a href="#" onClick={this.handleShowModal.bind(this, identity[0], identity[1], 'inactive')}>
```

Comment: Excellent.  Worked perfectly.  Thank you so much